# Given a vector $a$, is there a matrix $A$ such that $Ab = a \times b$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vectors, cross-product

If we let $$a = \begin{pmatrix}
        a_1 \\
        a_2\\
        a_3\\
        \end{pmatrix}$$

Is there a matrix $A$ such that $Ab = a \times b$ for all $b\in\mathbb{R}^3$?

Comment: Calculate $\vec a \times \vec b$.

Comment: You know there *has* to be, because the right side is linear in $b$ and all linear functions on vectors can be represented as matrices.

Comment: @AaronMontgomery In the answer by A. Monnet, I was able to reach the second step myself. The jump to the third step is the one I don't know how to make.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to know whether there is or not, the function $X \mapsto a\times X$ is linear application from $\mathbb{R}^3$ into $\mathbb{R}^3.$ Then it can be represented by a matrix $A \in \mathcal{M}_{3\times 3}(\mathbb{R}).$ To compute $A,$ let  $b = (x,y,z)^t.$ Then we have

$$ (a_1,b_2,a_3)^t \times (x,y,z)^t = \left( \begin{matrix} a_2z-a_3y\\ -a_1z+a_3x \\ a_1y -a_2x\end{matrix}\right) = \left( \begin{matrix} 0&-a_3& a_2\\ a_3&0&-a_1\\ -a_2&a_1&0\end{matrix}\right) b$$

Comment: How did you take the result of $a \times b$ and then determine that matrix $A$ would be the anti-symmetric matrix shown? I'm not seeing how you've made that jump.

Comment: @JakeBSc You can see it by comparing coefficients of a full matrix-vector product ((a11,a12,a13),(a21,a22,a23),(a31,a32,a33)).(x,y,z)=(a11*x+a21*y+a31*z, a12*x+a22*y+a32*z, a13*x+a23*y+a33*z) with the coefficients you see in the cross product result above and reverse engineer the matrix that way. It's also noteworthy, that this is exactly what (besides other things) the [Levi-Civita tensor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levi-Civita_symbol) expresses.

Comment: Kahan calls the mapping from the vector to the corresponding skew-symmetric matrix the ["cross operator"](https://people.eecs.berkeley.edu/~wkahan/MathH110/Cross.pdf).

Answer (score 2):

Using the [Levi-Civita](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levi-Civita_symbol) ($\epsilon$) tensor you can write the cross product as
$$\eqalign{
 c &= a\times b \cr
 c_i
 &= (\epsilon_{ijk} a_j) b_k = A_{ik} b_k \cr
}$$
So we just need a matrix whose components are given by
$$\eqalign{
 A_{ik} &= \epsilon_{ijk} a_j \cr
}$$
For example, the matrix elements corresponding to $a_1$ are 
$$\eqalign{
 A_{23} &= \epsilon_{213}\,a_1 = -a_1 \cr
 A_{32} &= \epsilon_{312}\,a_1 = +a_1 \cr
}$$ since $\epsilon_{ijk}$ equals $+1$ for an even permutation of its indices,  $-1$ for an odd permutation, and $0$ when any index is repeated.

You can also use the Levi-Civita tensor to reverse the process, i.e. given a skew-symmetric matrix $A$ find the vector $a$ from which it was constructed
$$\eqalign{
 a_i &= -\frac{1}{2}\epsilon_{ijk}\,A_{jk}\cr
}$$